# jQuery UI Dialog and IFRAME - with 'on' event handler

Tags: jquery

On the parent page of my IFRAME I have a jQuery event to detect a click on an element within the IFRAME. Clicking on this link opens up a jQuery UI dialog:

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="page.php">
    <div class="edit-content"></div>
</iframe>

$('#my-iframe').contents().find('body').on('click', '.edit-content', function(){
    $('#dialog', window.parent.document).dialog();
});
```

(the dialog content is stored in #dialog on the parent page)

Now on the dialog itself, I have a link to which I want to attach an 'on' event handler to:

```
<a href="#" class="edit-link" id="test-1">Test</a>

$('#dialog').on('click', $('.edit-link'), function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    return false;
});
```

However this is not returning the ID of the link, instead it is returning "dialog".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - it was an error in my original code - it should have been:

```
$('#dialog').on('click', '.edit-link', function(){
```

Instead of:

```
$('#dialog').on('click', $('.edit-link'), function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

this references the owner of the function, in your case this is dialog.
Try this instead:

```
$('#dialog .edit-link').live('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, but unfortunately it is not picking up newly created `.edit-link` elements..

Comment: Whoops, it was an error in my original code - it should have been: `$('#dialog').on('click', '.edit-link', function(){`

Comment: you should use the live method is you need it to pick up newly created objects as well, I will update my code.